# Springboot | RequestScope | @Async | Is their any way to identify that request is executing through Async thread OR main thread?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, asynchronous, requestscope

I'm facing issue where, sometimes, async thread is NOT copying Request Scope properties through :

```
@Override
      public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submit(
            new ContextAwareCallable(task, RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()));
      }

@Override


public T call() throws Exception {
    if (context != null) {
      RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);
    }
    try {
      return task.call();
    } finally {
      RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
    }
  }
```

Due to this, getting below exception:

```
**org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException:**
```

Error creating bean with name `'scopedTarget.sessionClient'`:
Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread;
consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;
`nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:` Cannot ask for request attribute - request is not active anymore!

Please suggest a concrete way to copy request attributes in new thread? OR way to identify that request is executing through Async thread OR main thread?

TIA